# Progress Notification not being cancelled

Tags: java, android, notifications

When I press the "Cancel" button in the notification, the notification still remains in the notification bar, and every time I press "Cancel" the notifications closes but still appears in the top bar, and when I open the notifications is still there, the notification is not being removed properly.

This is the code to create the progress notification, it works fine:

```
private void createProgressNotification() {

    PendingIntent dismissIntent = NotificationActivity.getDismissIntent(NOTIFICATION_PROGRESS, Analyse.this);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("URL Analysis")
                    .setContentText("Analysis in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "Cancel", dismissIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setProgress(0, 0, true);

    NotificationManager mNotifyManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_PROGRESS, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And this is the custom NotificationActivity class I have to handle the dismissIntent:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = "NOTIFICATION_ID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(getIntent().getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, -1));
        finish(); // since finish() is called in onCreate(), onDestroy() will be called immediately
    }

    public static PendingIntent getDismissIntent(int notificationId, Context context, AsyncCallWS analyze) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
        PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        return dismissIntent;
    }

}
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Change false to true in setAutoCancel() of NotificationCompat Builder property

```
  mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

so it will be

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("URL Analysis")
                .setContentText("Analysis in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "Cancel", dismissIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setProgress(0, 0, true);
```